# Unpacking a mixed-semantic Map into a case class

Tags: scala

I'm using an api that I can't change that returns a 2-element map where one key is always present but the other key/value pair is dynamic, and I'm trying to unpack them into a case class.  The code below works, but is really ugly:

```scala
case class Foo(name: String, key: String, value: String)

def fooFromMap(item: Map[String, String]): Option[Foo] = {
  var name: String = null
  var key: String = null
  var value: String = null
  item.foreach { 
    case ("name", v) => name = v
    case (k, v) => key = k; value = v
  }
  if(name != null && key != null && value != null) Some(Foo(name, key, value))
  else None
}
```

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is equivalent, and more idiomatic:

```
def fooFromMap(item: Map[String, String]): Option[Foo] = for {
  name   <- item get "name"
  (k, v) <- (item - "name").headOption
} yield Foo(name, k, v)
```

If either `item get "name"` or `(item - "name").headOption` comes up empty, the result will be empty—otherwise you get the `Foo` you want.

Comment: I know its premature optimization to gripe about it, but this allocates and burns a new Map instance.  It looks a lot nicer, but it still doesn't feel very good to me.

Comment: Yep, that sounds like premature optimization to me—especially since Scala has [specialized implementations](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map$.html) for small maps like this.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, the `Map` has always the `name` key and zero or one more key-value pair, right? If it is, you can do:

```
def fooFromMap(map: Map[String, String]) =
  map.get("name").map { name =>
    val (key, value) = (map - "name").head
    Foo(name, key, value)
  }
```

If you need to check also if the `Map` has a second pair (returning `None` if not), then:

```
def fooFromMap(map: Map[String, String]) = for {
  name <- map.get("name")
  (key, value) <- (map - "name").headOption
} yield Foo(name, key, value)
```

I tend to prefer the second snippet, as it is more idiomatic and makes use of the powerful `for` comprehensions in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fooFromMap(map: Map[String, String]): Option[Foo] = {
  val data = m.find(_._1 != "name").getOrElse (null, null)
  Foo(m.getOrElse("name", null), data._1, data._2) match { 
    case f: Foo if (f.name != null && f.key != null && f.value != null) => Some(f)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```